# How do I find Facebook URL in specific format

Tags: facebook

I have a FB post that includes text and an image. I want to share that post on Twitter, so I need the URL. If I right click on the date and time of the post and select "Copy Link Location" the URL that I get links to the post in a format that is unattractive - the image is on the left, and my text on the right. Example:

https://www.facebook.com/HealthForays/photos/a.1034954913325154/1187212074766103/?type=3&theater

shows:

[image]

I would like to have the post in the format where the image is above or below the text.
Is there an alternative URL/Can I modify the above URL to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove everything from the question mark onward.
In your example: https://www.facebook.com/HealthForays/posts/1187233111430666